PlayWright VS Code Inspector doesn't open inspector
I'm trying to record a test from the vs code extension.
When I click on record new, it opens chromium and new file, but dosn't open any isnpector or something like this, and when I navigate it dosn't record anything
How can I record my tests?

But when you run the cli command you can open the UI ?

When you start the record it is already started with recording mode. You can click on the record button to start recording if it does not record when you navigate. In the image , you can see the record button
